# Bodypix: using wasm for SIMD + multithreading

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js, bodypix

We are trying to use the WASM + SIMD + multithreading described [here](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/09/supercharging-tensorflowjs-webassembly.html) for bodypix. The sample web page linked to the article showed my MacBook Pro 2018 using both SIMD +
multithreading. However, we are having trouble trying to use it for our purposes with bodypix.

We are running this with electron 10.1 (Chromium 85.0.4183.84) and have tried running it with node and also as a web page loaded in index.html as script tags described the above article, but it hardly seems to use the GPU in each test and the experience is worse than running tensorflow in the CPU. We seem to be missing something to take advantage of it SIMD + multithreading.

When running in node, this is what the yarn package.json contained:

```
"@tensorflow-models/body-pix": "^2.0.5",
"@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.0.4",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm": "^2.3.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^2.3.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^2.3.0",
```

We did verify that the backend was set to wasm at runtime.

Anyone have any ideas what may be wrong?